# MySQL: how to call a stored procedure with only an output parameter?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

From my instruction book, I created the following procedure in which the INSERT statement will yield an error:

```
create procedure f1
(out error char(5))
begin
declare continue handler for SQLSTATE '23000'
set error='23000';
set error ='00000';
insert into teams values(2,27,'derde');
end;
```

However, it doesn't say how to call this procedure. I tried

```
call f1;

call f1();

call f1(error);
```

but none of these works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

some_variable = call f1();
It will work

Comment: Thanks guys, but both solutions generated errors :-( However, I found out one method that does work: call f1(@1);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: `CALL f1();`.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your stored procedure if you want to view the error values as a result. The SP like

```
**SELECT error**
```

and Please try to call procedure like

```
**CALL f1(@error)
SELECT @error**
```